# What is a proc map?

Tags: c, linux

Can anybody tell me what is a proc map? How it is useful and how to check it?

Thanks in advance.

Here is one of the proc maps, can someone explain what does it signify?

```
enter code here
-bash-3.2# cat /proc/2064/maps
 00008000-00009000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 33036189   /tmp/efence/dev.out
 00010000-00011000 rw-p 00000000 00:0e 33036189   /tmp/efence/dev.out
 00011000-00032000 rw-p 00011000 00:00 0          [heap]
 40000000-4001d000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 32247424   /devel/lib/ld-2.9.so
 4001d000-40020000 rw-p 4001d000 00:00 0 
 40024000-40025000 r--p 0001c000 00:0e 32247424   /devel/lib/ld-2.9.so
 40025000-40026000 rw-p 0001d000 00:0e 32247424   /devel/lib/ld-2.9.so
 40030000-40157000 r-xp 00000000 00:0e 32247431   /devel/lib/libc-2.9.so
 40157000-4015f000 ---p 00127000 00:0e 32247431   /devel/lib/libc-2.9.so
 4015f000-40161000 r--p 00127000 00:0e 32247431   /devel/lib/libc-2.9.so
 40161000-40162000 rw-p 00129000 00:0e 32247431   /devel/lib/libc-2.9.so
 40162000-40165000 rw-p 40162000 00:00 0 
 beb58000-beb6d000 rw-p befeb000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

Comment: Do you mean a linux process map ? If yes.. the answer is easy to find.. http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/linux-process-map-824005/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file `/proc/[pid]/maps` is a way to see the memory regions mapped by a process.  Read [about `/proc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) for more info on other useful stuff you can find there.

Comment: Thank you, can you share me some more details about it if you have?

Comment: @kingsmasher1: Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1401359/725163   then continue with Google or follow more links.