# missing [heap] section in /proc/pid/maps

Tags: c, memory

I'm experimenting with a simple C program that keeps allocating memory:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10000; i ++ )
{
    array[i] = malloc( 1024*1024 );
    if ( array[i] == NULL )
    {
        break;
    }
    printf("Sleeping...%d\n", i);
    sleep( 60 );
}
```

Full code pasted here: http://tny.cz/2d9cb3df

However, when I `cat /proc/pid/maps`, I get no `[heap]` section. Why?

```
08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:11 17         /data/a.out
08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:11 17         /data/a.out
0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:11 17         /data/a.out
0804b000-0805e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b74c6000-b75c8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b75c8000-b7775000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3539272    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
b7775000-b7777000 r--p 001ad000 08:01 3539272    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
b7777000-b7778000 rw-p 001af000 08:01 3539272    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
b7778000-b777b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7797000-b779a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b779a000-b779b000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
b779b000-b77bb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3539289    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
b77bb000-b77bc000 r--p 0001f000 08:01 3539289    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
b77bc000-b77bd000 rw-p 00020000 08:01 3539289    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
bff21000-bff42000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
```

Comment: The compiler deduces that the for loop doesn't do anything (i. e. no-op) and optimizes it out?

Comment: @H2CO3, I changed it to print out the allocated address and it's still the same.

Comment: @H2CO3 That seems like a big leap even for an overly aggressive optimizing compiler, as the loop contains three calls to functions that have quite big side-effects.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Well, yes, fair enough. (But I've seen "worse" optimizations produced by GCC and clang as well...)

Comment: @Mat code link added.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you're talking about `/proc/pid/maps` I assume you're on linux.

This is what `man malloc` tells me on the linux distribution I happen to run:

> Normally, `malloc()` allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts the size of the heap as required,  using  `sbrk(2)`.
>
> When  allocating  blocks  of memory larger than `MMAP_THRESHOLD` bytes, the glibc `malloc()` implementation allocates the memory as a private anonymous mapping using `mmap(2)`.  `MMAP_THRESHOLD` is 128 kB by default, but is  adjustable  using  `mallopt(3)`.
>
> Allocations  performed  using  `mmap(2)` are unaffected by the `RLIMIT_DATA` resource limit (see `getrlimit(2)`).

If you really want to see `[heap]` in your `/proc/pid/maps` allocate less than 128k per call to malloc.

Answer (score 1):

The said section is just not declared as "heap", as it is allocated via `mmap()` calls.

Here on my 64 bit system, the memory allocated comes from this constantly growing section:

```
7f7fbda7a000-7f7fbdc7c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
...
7f7fbc868000-7f7fbdc7c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
...
7f7fbc363000-7f7fbdc7c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

The section is extended at the start and the newly allocated memory always ias the start address + 0x10.

What the memory allocator does here is

```
mmap(NULL, 1052672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7fbb353000
```

Strange thing; I would have suspected that every `mmap()`ed memory section is shown separately. But if I have the program do intermediate `free()` calls, the memory allocation follows this:

```
7f16be944000-7f16bec47000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f16bed48000-7f16bee49000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
```

There has been made a hole in the otherwise contiguous memory.

And an additional thing happens: in this modified program, there is indeed a `[heap]` section. Due to reasuns beyond my understanding, the program swithces over to allocating via `brk()`, and this is (probably) where the heap comes from:

with every `brk()` call, the respective section is extended at its end:

```
01183000-029a4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

I do not know what has changed `malloc()`'s mind to take the "real" heap (the stuff connected to `brk()`) for the allocations. The first `munmap()` call, related to a respective `free()`, seems to produce this.

According to [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Malloc-Tunable-Parameters.html), there seems to be a maximum for `mmap()`ed chunks. If this is exceeded, gnulibc falls back to `brk()`/`sbrk()`, which operates on the "regular heap area".

So, shorter answer: The `malloc()`ed memory taken from via `brk()` is on the "real" `[heap]` section, the `mmap()`ed memory sections are not tagged as `[heap]`.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic allocations are made by using the `brk()` call. The start of the .brk section is calculated during program loading (look at load_elf_binary() in /linux/fs/binfmt_elf.c). However, a page is not mapped till during runtime when the actual allocation is requested. See below a screen show of the /proc/pid/maps before and after an allocation on an x86_64 system

**Before invoking a calloc(8032,1):**

```
$ cat /proc/$(pid)/maps

00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1314308             /testheap

00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:02 1314308             /testheap

00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:02 1314308             /testheap

7fafeea3e000-7fafeebfb000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 198420      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so

7fafeebfb000-7fafeedfb000 ---p 001bd000 08:02 198420      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
```

---

**After invoking a calloc(8032,1):**

```
$cat /proc/$(pid)/maps

00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1314308             /testheap

00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:02 1314308             /testheap

00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:02 1314308             /testheap

**021ea000-0220c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                   [heap]**

7fafeea3e000-7fafeebfb000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 198420      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so

7fafeebfb000-7fafeedfb000 ---p 001bd000 08:02 198420      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
```

---