# Determine how many times file is mapped into memory

Tags: c++, linux, shared-memory

Is it possible to get the total amount of memory maps on a specific file descriptor in Linux? For clearness I made a small example code how I open/create the memory map:

```
int fileDescriptor = open(mapname, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, 0666);
if(fileDescriptor < 0)
    return false;

//Map Semaphore
memorymap = mmap(NULL, sizeof(mapObject), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fileDescriptor, 0);
close(fileDescriptor);
```

The memory map is used by multiple processes. I have access to the code base of the other processes that are going to use this memory map. How can I get in a 100% correct way how many maps there are on the fileDescriptor?

Comment: Is it only going to be your processes that are opening the file?

Comment: @Ben There are multiple processes that are going to use the file.

Comment: Are all the processes owned by you? As in do you have the option to edit the code for anything that is accessing the file?

Comment: @Ben All those process are owned by me. I have full access to the code of all the programs that are going to use this.

Comment: I guess what i am getting at is can you make a short application that accepts socket connections from each of the applications that access the file. Then when they access it they connect this "other" program which tallies up its connections?

Comment: @lauw When you're giving a code example, it is always better to make it *complete*, if possible (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check all the `/proc/*/maps` files and count the number of times the memory-mapped file is mentioned.

For example, this is how the memory mapped "/tmp/delme" is mentioned

```
7fdb737d0000-7fdb737d1000 rw-s 00000000 08:04 13893648                   /tmp/delme
7fdb737d8000-7fdb737d9000 rw-s 00000000 08:04 13893648                   /tmp/delme
```

when using the following code:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 delme.cc && ./a.out
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int fileDescriptor = open("/tmp/delme", O_RDWR, 0664);
  if (fileDescriptor < 0) return false;
  auto memorymap = mmap (NULL, 123, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fileDescriptor, 0);
  auto memorymap2 = mmap (NULL, 123, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fileDescriptor, 0);
  close (fileDescriptor);
  std::ifstream mappings ("/proc/self/maps");
  std::cout << mappings.rdbuf() << std::endl;
}
```

See also [Understanding Linux /proc/id/maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-id-maps).

If you issue a global lock, preventing any mappings and unmappings from happening while the counting is taking the place, then this counter will be *100% correct*.