# What does /proc/pid/maps mean?

Tags: android, linux

When I analyse a app memory problem, I found its maps (`cat /proc/pid/maps`) like this:

```
 903 5fec1000-5fec2000 r--s 00001000 b3:10 98         /system/app/PacProcessor.apk

 904 5fec2000-5fec3000 r--s 00000000 b3:10 98         /system/app/PacProcessor.apk

 905 5fec3000-5fed7000 r--s 00560000 b3:10 125        /system/app/iReader.apk

 906 5fed7000-5ff09000 r--s 0019a000 b3:10 125        /system/app/iReader.apk

 907 5ff09000-5ff0b000 r--s 00043000 b3:10 81         /system/app/Galaxy4.apk

 908 5ff0b000-5ff0c000 r--s 00042000 b3:10 81         /system/app/Galaxy4.apk
```

It seems this app loads other app's code into its stack.

How can I avoid this kind memory allocation ?

Comment: what is the process name?
if it's a system process, then it is unavoidable. I guess you have to kill the apps themselves to release those resources.

Comment: yeah,it's a system app(not persistent,but installed at /system/app),but i checked other apps in /system/app dir,they don't have these allocation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Linux /proc/pid/maps or /proc/self/maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-pid-maps-or-proc-self-maps)

Answer (score 1):

From proc manual on Linux:

```
 /proc/[pid]/maps
          A file containing the currently mapped memory regions and  their  access  permissions.   See
          mmap(2) for some further information about memory mappings.
```

Comment: thanks,i almost know what they mean,but i can't figure it out why this app has so many allocation like that.and i want ot reduce this kind memory alloc