# How to get the current amount of heap allocated by an application?

Tags: linux, heap-memory

How can i get the amount of heap space (as numerical value, not as percentage) my application is currently using?

I would like such an output to write a script which finds out the maximum amount of memory my application has used.

Answer (score 0):

The information is stored in `/proc/<pid>/maps`, with `<pid>` being the Process ID of your application.
Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-id-maps) question for further informations.