# android mmap fails with out of memory

Tags: android, memory, android-ndk, mmap

I've searched everywhere for an answer but I think I'm hitting the limits of what I can find. My question seems somewhat related to this one : [Android NDK mmap call broken on 32-bit devices after upgrading to Lollipop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180268/android-ndk-mmap-call-broken-on-32-bit-devices-after-upgrading-to-lollipop) but no answer has been provided.

My problem is that I try to memory map 457232384 bytes from a file through a mmap call. On two different devices (Samsung Galaxy Note 3 & OnePlus One, 3GB RAM each) with Android 5.1.1, that call fails with errno 12 "Out of memory". Actually, the call fails when I try to allocate more than 300MB of memory. 313524224 bytes (299MB) works, 314572800 (300MB) won't.

Thing is, the very same call works on a third device which stayed on Android 4.4.2. Even stranger, this call works on the Android ARM emulator with SDK 21 (Android 5.0). Needless to say, the same amount of data (not mmap'ed) can be loaded without any issue.

dmesg reports this to me:

```
<3>[ 1137.488411] [0:Thread-298: 4267] arch_get_unmapped_area (TASK_SIZE - len < addr) len=457232384 task size=3204448256 pid=4267 do_align=0 addr=3034054656 mmap_base=3069939712
```

The function (from openfst) which tries to map the file is the following:

```
MappedFile* MappedFile::Map(istream* s, const FstReadOptions &opts,
                        size_t size) {
  size_t pos = s->tellg();

  if (opts.mode == FstReadOptions::MAP && pos >= 0 &&
      pos % kArchAlignment == 0) {
    int fd = open(opts.source.c_str(), O_RDONLY);
    if (fd != -1) {
      int pagesize = getpagesize();
      off_t offset = pos % pagesize;
      off_t upsize = size + offset;
      void *map = mmap(NULL, upsize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, pos - offset);
      char *data = reinterpret_cast<char*>(map);
      if (close(fd) == 0 && map != MAP_FAILED) {
        MemoryRegion region;
        region.mmap = map;
        region.size = upsize;
        region.data = reinterpret_cast<void*>(data + offset);
        MappedFile *mmf = new MappedFile(region);
        s->seekg(pos + size, ios::beg);
        if (s) {
          VLOG(1) << "mmap'ed region of " << size << " at offset " << pos
                  << " from " << opts.source.c_str() << " to addr " << map;
          return mmf;
        }
        delete mmf;
      } else {
        LOG(INFO) << "Mapping of file failed: " << strerror(errno);
      }
    }
  }
  // If all else fails resort to reading from file into allocated buffer.
  if (opts.mode != FstReadOptions::READ) {
    LOG(WARNING) << "File mapping at offset " << pos << " of file "
                 << opts.source << " could not be honored, reading instead.";
  }
  MappedFile* mf = Allocate(size);
  if (!s->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(mf->mutable_data()), size)) {
    delete mf;
    return NULL;
  }
  return mf;
}
```

Return from mmap is MAP_FAILED everytime.

Does someone has suggestions on where can I look to solve my issue?
Thanks!

EDIT :

here is the content of /proc/self/maps right after the infamous mmap call : http://pastebin.com/1864jZC2

A little gap analysis:

```
Gap between 00000000 and 12c00000 (diff = 314572800 bytes, 300 MB)
Gap between 42c00000 and 55281000 (diff = 308809728 bytes, 294.50390625 MB)
Gap between 67e80000 and 67ea4000 (diff = 147456 bytes, 0.140625 MB)
Gap between 7778b000 and 77800000 (diff = 479232 bytes, 0.45703125 MB)
Gap between 77a80000 and 77a82000 (diff = 8192 bytes, 0.0078125 MB)
Gap between 77c00000 and 77c04000 (diff = 16384 bytes, 0.015625 MB)
Gap between 78080000 and 780b7000 (diff = 225280 bytes, 0.21484375 MB)
Gap between 79ac1000 and 79ac2000 (diff = 4096 bytes, 0.00390625 MB)
Gap between 7db70000 and 7db71000 (diff = 4096 bytes, 0.00390625 MB)
Gap between 7e000000 and 7e001000 (diff = 4096 bytes, 0.00390625 MB)
Gap between 7e0fe000 and 7e0ff000 (diff = 4096 bytes, 0.00390625 MB)
Gap between 7e145000 and 7e146000 (diff = 4096 bytes, 0.00390625 MB)
Gap between b6fb9000 and be6ff000 (diff = 125067264 bytes, 119.2734375 MB)
Gap between beeff000 and ffff0000 (diff = 1091506176 bytes, 1040.94140625 MB)
```

EDIT:

the solution that worked for me in the comments of @fadden's answer.

TL;DR: set `dalvik.vm.heapsize` to `512m`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dump a copy of `/proc/self/maps` after `mmap()` fails (just open the file from your code and copy the contents to a temp file).  You may be having a problem getting a large contiguous virtual address range due to [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Some of the Zip file handling code in Android was using `mmap()` to map the entire file, and just operate on it in memory.  One day somebody created a 1GB Zip file and was unable to open it.  While the process' virtual address space had enough free pages, there weren't enough *contiguous* pages to create a single linear mapping.  (IIRC, the solution was to `mmap()` just the central directory.)

The `maps` output will show you what your process' address space looks like.  300MB seems a bit low for ASLR / fragmentation to be an issue, but it's a good place to start looking, and might explain the inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Hi @fadden, thanks for your answer! I've updated my question with the content of /proc/self/maps, I must admit I'm not very used to read this kind of output, I hope you can help me understand it.

Comment: The numbers on the left are address ranges in hex. 0x00000000 through 0xbfffffff are available to 32-bit programs. Skimming your output, it looks like there's a lot of stuff in memory, with a big gap between the end of a dalvik region at 42c00000, and the start of `HCLG.fst.map` at 55281000. Subtracting those indicates the region is ~294MB, so a 300MB allocation would fail. (I don't know if that's actually the largest contiguous open space, but it looked like one of the bigger ones.) cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-id-maps

Comment: Hi @fadden, thanks again for your help. I've updated my question with a gap analysis and it seems you're right. In your opinion, what should be done about that?

Comment: Looking at your breakdown, the various allocations and fragmentation have left you with about 700MB of free virtual address space broken into three chunks. `mmap()` requires a contiguous address region. If some of those allocations were under your control you could try forcing the mappings to have fixed addresses to reduce the fragmentation, but that rarely ends well. You will most likely need to find a way to reduce the size of the mapped regions, e.g. by creating separate mappings for sub-sections of the file.

Comment: Hi @fadden, thanks for your help. I've finally found a solution (more of a workaround, but still) and it works: I've reduced the `dalvik.vm.heapsize` prop to 512m (from 768m). What helped me is your answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180268/android-ndk-mmap-call-broken-on-32-bit-devices-after-upgrading-to-lollipop, reading that the ART heap was effectively 768MB on my device reminded me the heapsize prop. Anyway, thanks for all.

Comment: Interesting. That requires a rooted device, which limits its usefulness for most app authors, but could be helpful for certain projects.

Comment: Very interesting thread.  I've been having problems on Android with Qt apps which memory-map Qt's "qrc"/"rcc" resource files.  qrc files above ~300MByte seemed to fail on *some* devices/OS versions, and it's the size of individual resource files rather than the total of multiple resource files that causes trouble.  This /proc/self/maps thing looks like it's the key to understanding what's going on.

Comment: Hi! Very helpful thread. I had the same problem, like the one you described in the initial question. mmaping ~200mb fails on Oreo, but it used to pass on Nougat (on the same device), and the solution you proposed (reducing dalvik.vm.heapsize) helped. Have you made any effort towards understanding why exactly this fixes the out of memory error? I can't seem to wrap my head around it, how does reducing heap size lead to more available memory for that process.

Comment: @shadowfire - strictly speaking, the issue isn't "having enough memory", it is "having a large enough contiguous LOGICAL ADDRESS space". See in question how addresses range from 00000000 to ffffffff. If you reduce the size of any of the large allocations (in this case, reducing dalvik heapsize), then one of its neighboring "gaps" is larger, so a large mmap is more likely to be possible, as mmap is looking for an available address range. This is a "memory virtualization" situation: each process has a 32-bit "logical address" range. Isn't phone's physical memory.