# Reconstructing "flags" argument to mmap call

Tags: c, linux

One of the arguments to `mmap` is `flags`. To what extent is it possible to reconstruct which flags were used with the information in `/proc/self/maps`?

Comment: Why would `fd` be useful? Only the process itself would know/care. You already have the filename.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: hadn't thought about that - I'll edit the question then.  My question regarding the flags still remains though - can I determine those from `/proc/self/maps`?

Comment: `MAP_PRIVATE` and `MAP_SHARED` flags may be determined from `permissions` column. `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is determined by empty path. Some flags like `MAP_FIXED` are probably not saved anywhere after `mmap()` returns. Some flags may be probably determined from `/proc/self/smaps`.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512704/how-can-i-find-the-mapped-file-when-its-not-shown-in-proc-maps

Comment: @g-v:  I'd consider your second comment to be the answer I was looking for - if you'd like, convert that into an answer and I'll accept it.  As for the possible duplicate - I agree these questions are very similar, I was specifically looking for how to reconstruct the `flags` argument, which is how it differs.  I can try to edit the question to make that more explicit.

Comment: @tonysdg, ok, I'm not insisting on duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See details on `/proc/self/maps` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-id-maps).

Some ideas (actually not a full answer):

- `MAP_PRIVATE` and `MAP_SHARED` flags may be determined from permissions column
- `MAP_ANONYMOUS` is determined by empty path
- some flags (probably `MAP_HUGETLB`, `MAP_LOCKED`) may be determined from `/proc/self/smaps`
- some flags like `MAP_FIXED` (probably `MAP_32BIT`, `MAP_UNINITIALIZED`) are most likely not saved anywhere after `mmap()` returns
- some flags (`MAP_NONBLOCK`, `MAP_NORESERVE`, `MAP_POPULATE`) are likely to be stored somewhere, but I don't think they're accessible through `/proc`

HTH