# Inspection of binary file's mapping

Tags: linux, memory, mapping, memory-profiling

If I run some program under Linux I can see in /proc/pid/smaps that part of its binary is mapped to physical memory. For example:

```
08047000-0804d000 r-xp 00000000 b4:04 2845       /usr/bin/test_prog
Size:                 24 kB
Rss:                  20 kB
Pss:                  20 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:        20 kB
Private_Dirty:         0 kB
Referenced:           20 kB
...
```

(mapped 20 out of 24 kB)

How can I see exactly which parts of binary is mapped? If I understand right, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-id-maps) answer field **address** in /proc/pid/maps shows starting and ending addresses of whole file in virtual memory. Which tool can I use to investigate which part of virtual memory, where binary is loaded, mapped to RAM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/proc/pid/pagemap` can give such information. Documentation is [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt).