# gdb command to get the virtual memory page's permissions for a given address

Tags: debugging, segmentation-fault, gdb, memory-address

Is there a command in gdb that will allow me to see if the memory page where my app crashed has Read/Write/Execute permissions?

Basically what I want is something like when I'm entering:

```
gdb:> addrinfo 0x12345678
```

And I get:

```
address 0x12345678 is in range ....
which is occupied by executable image (if any)...../my-lib.so
vm page permsissions: RWX
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this info in  "/proc/'pid_of_your_app'/maps" file. Please check [Understanding Linux /proc/id/maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-id-maps) for more info.

If you often need to lookup addresses in maps file, you can write a small script to do this...