# Base and limit addresses from /proc/<pid>/

Tags: linux, process

Can we check the base and limit addresses using `cat /proc/<pid>/?`. I read the [man page of proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/procfs.5.html) but I couldn't find or missed which file contains the mentioned addresses.

[What I mean with base and limit](https://silo.tips/download/what-is-the-base-register-and-what-is-the-limit-register)

Comment: `the base and limit addresses` What is a "base address" and a "limit address"? What are these?

Comment: The linked doc refers to physical address.  A user process does not have any information about physical addresses.

Answer (score 3):

What you have linked to is a vastly simplified address space concept more suited to a microcontroller.  It is far more complex in Linux and a modern CPU.

But you can get information like this from `/proc/<pid>/`.  Look in `maps` and `smaps`.  `maps` will have lines like this:

```
55bf12c35000-55bf12c62000 r--p 00000000 103:02 548822                    /usr/bin/bash
```

The first two numbers are the base and limit of this individual mapping.  But there is not just one address space mapping per process.  There are dozens if not hundreds.

`smaps` will have these lines plus additional information on each mapping.

There already a question about these files with a good answer, [Understanding Linux /proc/id/maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401359/understanding-linux-proc-id-maps).  Also look at the docs in the man page for proc(5).

Comment: Thanks. I also have sort of unrelated question. If I check the GDTR, then I should find a base and limit values. In my case it is always returning the same value. Should it do so? and assume the values where changing, if I understand your question correctly, we have multiple base and limit for the same program, so which ones should show in the GDTR?