# C Static and Auto allocation

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, operating-system, allocation

When a **C** program is started how does it ask the operating system enough memory space for static variables?
And while running how does it ask the operating system memory space for automatic variables?

I would also like to know how it releases these memory spaces after execution.

Please try to be the most accurate possible. If operating systems varies in their explanations please give preference to UNIX-like ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Global variables and those with static life time** are usually stored in a data segment which is setup by the operating system's executable loader.

This loader probably does, what @John Zwinck said on Unix. On Windows there is VirtualAlloc for example, which can also be used to allocate memory in the address space of another program.

**Local variables** are usually stored on the so called stack. Allocations on the stack are pretty fast as they usually just consist of a modification of the stack pointer register (sp, esp, rsp on x86 processor family). So when you have an int (size: 4 bytes) that register would simply be decremented by 4 as the stack grows downwards. At the end of the scope the old state of the stack register is restored.

Also this makes stack overflows dangerous wher you can overwrite other variables on the stack that should not be modified, like return addresses of function calls.

**Dynamic variables** are variables allocated using malloc (C) or new (C++) or any of the operating system specific allocation functions. These are placed on the so called heap. These live until they are cleaned up using free/delete/os-specific-deallocator or the program exits (in that case a sane operating system takes care of the cleanup).

Also dynamic allocation is the slowest of the three as it requires a call to the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

Memory allocation on Unix-like systems is done via calls to the operating system using the [`sbrk()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk) and [`mmap()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mmap) APIs.

`sbrk()` is used to enlarge the "data segment" which is a contiguous range of (virtual) addresses.  `mmap()` is used in many modern systems as a sort of supplement to this, because it can allocate chunks which can later be deallocated independently (meaning no "holes" will remain as can happen with `sbrk()`).

In C you have `malloc()` as the user-facing API for memory allocation.  You can read more about how that maps to the low-level functions I mentioned earlier, here: [How are malloc and free implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358045/how-are-malloc-and-free-implemented)

Answer (score 2):

Static variables are found in the BSS segment behind the code. Auto variables are located on the stack at the end of the virtual memory of the process. Both are defined at compile time. The memory layout is then created at program startup.
brk(), sbrk() and mmap() can manipulate the virtual memory (the heap in particular) at run time (e.g. with malloc()/free()) but these functions are not related to static and auto variables!