# how do compilers assign memory addresses to variables?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, linker, operating-system

I teach a course where students get to ask questions about programming (!): I got this question:

> Why does the machine choose were variables go in memory? Can we tell
>   it where to store a variable?

I don't really know what to say. Here's my first attempt:

> The compiler (not the machine) chooses where to store the variables in the process address 
>   space automatically. Using C, we cannot tell the machine where to store variables.

But that "automatically" is somewhat anticlimactic and begs the question... and I've realized I don't even know if it's the compiler or the runtime or the OS or who does the assignment. Maybe someone can answer the student's question better than me.

Comment: Technically it's the [linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) that does this.

Comment: `Using C, we cannot tell the machine where to store variables` maybe not standard C, but any dialect used for a DSP/microcontroller will use some extension to allow you to put the variable in SDRAM/IRAM/EEPROM/...

Comment: Consider reading [Linkers and Loaders](http://linker.iecc.com/) by John R. Levine.

Comment: @haccks only partly, as Michael says the linker does the core job. This can be seen easily by letting the linker generate a map file which basically shows you 'this variable goes there, the stack goes there, this other section goes there' etc

Comment: Isn't it the Operating System that decides where the variables are stored? When a program is started, I think, the OS allocates a Virtual Space in memory for it to use. Both the stack and heap are located inside this Space. Global Variables and Local Variables (automatic) are put in the stack; the former when the program starts and deleted when it terminates, the latter when they are declared and deleted when out of scope.

Comment: @angel yes that's true, but the OS just says 'here's a piece of memory starting at address x'. Where exactly in that piece the stack/heap/... are placed is decided by the linker.

Comment: So, it seems to be both the OS and the Linker that decide...

Comment: "Why does the machine choose" rephrased as "How does the machine choose" - really refocuses on the gist of the question, and which software does what in this regard (OS, compiler/assembler etc.) - a pointer in C with a poorly specified address can really mess things up for instance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The answer to this question is quite complex since there are various approaches to memory allocation depending on variable scope, size and programming environment.

### Stack allocated variables

Typically `local variables` are put on the "stack". This means that the compiler assigns an offset to the "stack pointer" which can be different depending on the invocation of the current function. I.e. the compiler assumes that memory locations like Stack-Pointer+4, Stack-Pointer+8, etc. are accessible and usable by the program. Upon `return`-ing  from the function the memory locations are not guaranteed to retain these values.

This is mapped into assembly instructions similar to the following. `esp` is the stack pointer, `esp + N` refers to a  memory location relative to esp:

```
mov eax, DWORD PTR SS:[esp]
mov eax, DWORD PTR SS:[esp + 4]
mov eax, DWORD PTR SS:[esp + 8]
```

### Heap

Then there are variables that are heap-allocated. This means that there is a library call to request memory from the standard library (`alloc` in C or `new` in C++). This memory is reserved until the end of the programs execution. `alloc` and `new` return pointers to memory in a region of memory called the heap. The allocating functions have to make sure that the memory is not reserved which can make heap-allocation slow at times. Also, if you don't want to run out of memory you should `free` (or `delete`) memory that is not used anymore. Heap allocation is quite complicated internally since the standard library has to keep track of used and unsused ranges in memory as well as freed ranges of memory. Therefore even freeing a heap-allocated variable can be more time-consuming than allocating it. For more information see [How is malloc() implemented internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479330/how-is-malloc-implemented-internally)

Understanding the difference between stack and heap is quite fundamental to learning how to program in C and C++.

### Arbitrary Pointers

Naively one might assume, that by setting a pointer to an arbitrary address `int *a = 0x123` it should be possible to address arbitrary locations in the computer's memory. This does not exactly hold true since (depending on the CPU und system) programs are heavily restricted when addressing memory.

### Getting a feel for memory

In a guided classroom experience, it might be beneficial to explore some simple C code by compiling source code to assembler (gcc can do this for example). A simple function such as `int foo(int a, int b) { return a+b;}` should suffice (without optimizations). Then see something like `int bar(int *a, int *b) { return (*a) + (*b);}`;

When invoking bar, allocate the parameters once on the stack, once per malloc.

### Conclusion

The compiler does perform some variable placment and alignment relative to base-adresses which are obtained by the program/standard library at runtime.

For a deep understanding of memory related questions see Ulrich Drepper's "What every programmer should know about memory" http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.91.957

### Apart from C-ish Country idenote

Then there also is Garbage Collection which is popular among lots of scripting languages (Python, Perl, Javascript, lisp) and device independent environments (Java, C#). It is related to heap allocation but slightly more complicated.

Varieties of programming languages are only heap-based (stackless python) or entirely stack based (forth).

Comment: It would be nice to also discuss static data (usually called "data/rodata/bss" sections), and maybe also static code ("text"). These are sections of code which are laid out by the linker and whose addresses are largely predictable.

Answer (score 8):

I think the answer to this question starts with an understanding of the layout of a program in memory.  Underneath the operating system, a computer's main memory is just a giant array.  When you run a program, the operating system will take a chunk of this memory and break it up into logical sections for the following purposes:

- stack:  this area of memory stores information about all functions currently in scope, including the currently running function and all of its ancestors.  Information stored includes local variables and the address to return to when the function is done.
- heap:  this area of memory is used when you want to dynamically allocate some storage.  Generally your local variable would then contain an address (ie, it would be a pointer) in the heap where your data is stored, and you could publish this address to other parts of your program without worrying that your data will be overwritten when the current function goes out of scope.
- data, bss, text segments:  these are more or less outside the scope of this particular question, but they store things such as global data and the program itself.

Hope that helps.  There are lots of good resources online as well.  I just googled "layout of a program in memory" and found this one:  http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add few. For firmware where you know the memory map and run address, and where you compile source using your own linker script-

You can assign a custom section to a variable using section attribute and then assign a particular address to custom section through linker script. Then variable would get a fixed/assigned address.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables within a function will typically be laid out sequentially within the function's stack frame.

Comment: Local variables are typically grouped by alignment requirements. This reduces the space required by allowing several `char` objects to be stored adjacent to each other in one word, et cetera. If you laid them out in sequence (e.g., by appearance of declaration), you would have to include more padding bytes.