# Change the address of a pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, storage, dma

I have an Array of integers called bufferA[] and a pointer *ptr which points to the first integer in this Array bufferA[0]. Now, i would like to Change the pointer to point to the second value bufferA[1]. As i debbug the Code i can see that the address of the first integer in this Array is 0x1702 and now i would like to Change the pointer so it Points to 0x1704 which is the address of bufferA[1].
There is probably some way to make this without the pointer and just read the values of the Array, but this Array is passed from the ADC-module to the DMA-module and instead of just taking the Arrays (which makes storing them in the DMA useless) i would like to just take the address of the first value and change it up to read the following values.
i hope this somehow explains my Problem...

Comment: so do you want the memory address of the first element of the bufferA [] array? and which language you need?

Comment: I'm writing in c, I would like to know how to set the address of a pointer basically, something like *ptr=&(0x1702) so it points to the first element and then somehow change the address *ptr=&(0x1702 + 2) so it points to the second element

Comment: look at this question [Where are addresses of pointers stored in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198834/where-are-addresses-of-pointers-stored-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: You're thinking too hard. `ptr = &bufferA[0];`, `ptr = &bufferA[1];`, ...

Comment: You could just do `ptr++;`

Answer (score 0):

How about `ptr = ptr + 1;`?  (Or equivalently in this context `ptr += 1;` or `ptr++;` or `++ptr;`?)  The C compiler knows how many bytes are taken up by the item that `ptr` points to, because of its declared type, and will automatically increment the pointer by the right number of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

**Arrays in C are always passed by reference, there is no copy operation of you pass it as an argument to a function!** (This is a first gotcha of beginner C programmers)

Read something about pointers in C, first, but in short:

```
int a = 5;    // declares a integer-type of value 5
int* pta;     // declares a pointer-to-integer type
pta = &a      // assigns the **address** of a to pta (e.g. 0x01)
int b = *pta  // assingns the **value** of the address location that pta is pointing to into b
              // (i.e. the contents of memory address 0x01, which is 5)
*pta = 4      // assigns 4 to the content of the memory address that pta is pointing to.

// now b is 5, because we assigned the value of the address that pta was pointing to
// and a is 4, because we changed the value of the address that pta was pointing to
// - which was the address where variable a was stored
```

The variable `bufferA` is itself a pointer to the address of the first element. `bufferA + 1` gives you the address of the second element, because arrays are stored in memory sequentially.

Or if you want a more readable format:

```
&bufferA[0]  is the same as  bufferA         (address of the first element(e.g 0x11) 
&bufferA[1]  is the same as  bufferA + 1     (address of the second element(e.g 0x12) 
buffer[2]    is the same as  *(buffer + 2)   (value at the address of the third element)
```