# How are we able to access the pointer after deallocating the memory?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

As per my understanding,

free() is used to deallocate the memory that we allocated using malloc before.

In my following snippet, I have freed the memory i have allocated. But i was able to access the pointer even after freeing? How it is possible?

How free works internally?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int *p=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
   *p=17;
   free(p);
   *p=*p+1;
   printf("\n After freeing memory :: %d ",*p );
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The memory is still there, and is not usually overwritten immediately. However, future calls to malloc will eventually re-use that memory.

Comment: You could invoke equally undefined behavior by never allocating memory in the first place and simply dereferencing an indeterminate pointer. In your code, the validity of the address enclosed in your pointer is lost as soon as `free()` is invoked, and as such even evaluating it, much less dereferencing it, invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly continue to use `p` after calling `free(p)` and nothing will stop you. However the results will be completely undefined and unpredictable. It works by luck only. This is a common programming error called "[use after free](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/416.html)" which works in many programs for literally **years** without "problems" -- until it causes a problem.

There are tools which are quite good at finding such errors, such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Great!  Yes you are right, this is  one of the undefined behavior in c.

Comment: Jeremy, your answer doesn't explain how free works internally.

Comment: @Samveen True, I basically assumed that part of the question is somewhat rhetorical since Googling for "how does free work" yields innumerable resources.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing  a [dangling pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) will result in undefined behavior.
A dangling pointer is the one which is already freed.

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain how free works internally, just the language specification take on what shouldn't be done.

Comment: Update your answer as well (in the off case it gets flagged)

Answer (score 1):

After `free(p)`, `p` is a dangling pointer which points to no where. `free()` just releases the memory block allocated by `malloc()` and it doesn't change the value of pointer pointing to heap in that process address space. On some platforms you might get segfault if you try dereferencing pointer after freeing. Its good practice if you assign pointer `p` to `NULL` after freeing.

Comment: "Its good practice if you assign pointer p to NULL after freeing." - A very good practice every body should do

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain how free works internally, just the language specification take on what shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 1):

In most systems and standard libraries, `malloc` is optimized by allocating a larger chunk of memory than required (up to 64K on some systems) from the OS, and then internally disbursing it as per requirement from this pool. The same applied to the deallocation (`free`) as well, in that, the `free`'d memory isn't freed, but put back in the memory pool, in case another request comes in, in which case the pool is reused.

Thus, the call to `free` hasn't actually freed the memory from the process's address space and is thus accessible even after free.

My understanding as to why this is done is that system calls are expensive, so the initial call to `malloc` will make a system call for enough memory that future requests for `malloc` do not immediately trigger another system call for more memory.

As for further reading, please take a look at [this page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), [How do malloc() and free() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work) and [How is malloc() implemented internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479330/how-is-malloc-implemented-internally)