# Why does a double free() not crash the program?

Tags: c, malloc, free

As per my understanding below program could have been crashed as freeing already freed memory but its not. Running on my Linux machine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main(void) {
      int *ptr1 = NULL;
      ptr1 = malloc(100);
      free(ptr1);
      free(ptr1);
      printf("%d\n", *ptr1);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where does it say that a program *must* crash?

Comment: A better question is why this would ever *compile*.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are we able to access the pointer after deallocating the memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033822/how-are-we-able-to-access-the-pointer-after-deallocating-the-memory)

Comment: Include the proper headers (`<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` respectively for the prototypes of `printf()` and `malloc()`), turn on **all** your compiler warnings and **mind them**.

Comment: @EOF Whats wrong in compilation. its run time thing btw.

Comment: `ptr1 = malloc("100");`You are using a string literal as an argument to malloc(). This *might* be treated as a very large integer value, causing malloc() to return NULL. And double freeing NULL is not a sin. But at least your compiler should complain. And you should `#include <stdlib.h>` EXTRA: `malloc.h` is a non-standard headerfile.

Comment: Do you mean "crash because I called `free` twice", or do you mean "crash because I am dereferencing a pointer to memory I do not own", or do you mean "crash because I am printing an uninitialised value"?

Comment: @KaushalBillore I believe there is no implicit conversion from `char[]` to `size_t`.

Comment: @KaushalBillore you ask "Whats wrong in compilation". The original `malloc`line generated 2 compiler warnings in MSVC.

Comment: Obviously, you either never compiled/tested it at all, or you did not copy/paste in the code you are actually using :((

Comment: Causing undefined behavior twice. "Undefined" means... "NOT DEFINED".   So crash/no crash is not defined in this case

Comment: If your C library is built with double free detection you may enable it. `glibc` has one, for example.

Comment: @wildplasser  '"100"' was typo error.

Comment: Don't post typo errors.

Answer (score 2):

According to the definition of [free](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf), a double `free` achieves undefined behaviour:

> 7.20.3.2 The free function
>
> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made available for further
>   allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the calloc,
>   malloc, or realloc function, **or if the space has been deallocated by
>   a call to free or realloc, the behavior is undefined**.

And undefined behaviour itself is defined in the same standard as follows:

> 3.4.3 (1) undefined behavior
>
> behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or
>   of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no
>   requirements NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the
>   situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during
>   translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic
>   of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic
>   message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance
>   of a diagnostic message)

So a program with undefined behaviour may "crash", but it also may not. It's undefined...

Comment: That document linked is not the C standard and never has been. If you cite, please use the valid version!