# Understanding and implementing malloc

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

How is malloc implemented internally ? How to implement malloc with below necessary conditions

•   Malloc allocates at least the number of bytes requested

•   The pointer returned by malloc points to an allocated space ( i.e. a space where the program can read or write successfully;)

•   No other call to malloc will allocate this space or any portion of it, unless the pointer has been freed before.

•   malloc should be tractable: malloc must terminate in as soon as possible (it should not be NP-hard !;)

•   Malloc should also provide resizing and freeing.

The function obey to the following signature:
Void * malloc(size_t size);

Comment: can u provide reason for downgrading ? or better other SO thread which covers the topic in detail ?

Comment: i am not among them, but i think your question shows no research effort. that's why.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr : I have gone through both of the below link and each of the answer provided - Also just because i didnt get it through SO I kept searching for better answer and found one through that tutorial, so thought of sharing with community  - Related SO links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479330/how-is-malloc-implemented-internally

Comment: And I am quite sure the person who downvoted didnot take effort to read tutorial I posted - had he taken the effort would have taken him atleast 10mins before downvoting -

Comment: there are people like that. i've pretty much got used to them.

Answer (score 9):

Solution: 
In order to code a malloc, we need to know where the heap begin and the break position,
and of course we need to be able to move the break. We shall use sbrk() sys call to achieve this.

[image]

Sbrk (n) move the break by the given increment n (in bytes.)

Special case of sbrk: when increment is null (i.e. sbrk (0)), the returned value is the actual break address (the previous and the new break addresses are the same.) sbrk is thus used to retrieve the beginning of the heap which is the initial position of the break

Step -1 Implementation (Does not satisfy all criteria)
[image]

But at high level goal is satisfied it would move the break point by size requested and user would get memory allocation on heap, without satisfying criteria to do realloc and allow it to free
1)  So we need to know where each portion begins and when we are at beginning of each portion address of next one.
2)  What is the size of that portion
3)  If that portion is free or not
[image]

**So basically we need a list with below content**
[image]

Using int for free might seem a bad idea but since struct are aligned by default it wont matter.

Another condition we have to take care is malloc must return aligned address. As seen above meta part is already aligned we just need to make sure data part is as well.
[image]

**Finding a chunk**
Base is a global pointer to starting point of heap
[image]

**Extending Heap** – Its simple we just move the break point.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Now we can do our malloc function which is just wrapper of all small blocks gone through**
[image]

Comment: Do you from which book/site/tutorial those images are?

Comment: I found it. This [PDF](http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/Malloc_tutorial.pdf) has the complete tutorial from where he got the images.

Comment: I have already kept it yesterday - but I was pointed to fact external links can break - so I just posted snippet from tutorial - below answer is there for your reference

Answer (score 2):

### brk() and sbrk()

From the [manual(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/brk) of **brk()**.

> **brk()** and **sbrk()** change the location of the *program break*, which defines the end of the process's data segment (i.e., the program break is the first location after the end of the uninitialized data segment). Increasing the program break has the effect of allocating memory to the process; decreasing the break deallocates memory.
>
> **brk()** sets the end of the data segment to the value specified by addr, when that value is reasonable, the system has enough memory, and the process does not exceed its maximum data size (see **setrlimit(2)**).
>
> **sbrk()** increments the program's data space by increment bytes. Calling 
>    **sbrk()** with an increment of 0 can be used to find the current location of 
>    the program break.

I'll use that because, honestly, I can't define those functions any better. Keep in mind that both **brk()** and **sbrk()** are [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) provided by the [Linux Kernel](http://linux.die.net/man/2/brk). This is the first main difference between them and the **malloc()** family - **malloc() and brothers** are [GLibC](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) Implementations.

This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988487/what-does-brk-system-call-do) will tell you exactly what they do and what is the program break, so I won't copy all of that here.

### malloc(), calloc(), free()

As said, they're implemented by GLibC and manage memory blocks on the system through a list. **Simply put**(and let me stress the *simple* part), **malloc()** will find a free block on that list that fits the size requested by the user and return that block's address and mark it as *in use*; **free()**, on the other hand, will return that block to the list.

You can download the sources from [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/). As of now, the latest is **2.22**. Once downloaded, extract and go to **glibc-2.22/malloc**. Under this directory you'll find the source for malloc (malloc.c).

Extracted from the first comment section on the *malloc.c* file:

> The main properties of the algorithms are:
>
> - For large (>= 512 bytes) requests, it is a pure best-fit allocator,
>     with ties normally decided via FIFO (i.e. least recently used).
> - For small (<= 64 bytes by default) requests, it is a caching
>     allocator, that maintains pools of quickly recycled chunks.
> - In between, and for combinations of large and small requests, it does
>     the best it can trying to meet both goals at once.
> - For very large requests (>= 128KB by default), it relies on system
>     memory mapping facilities, if supported.
>
> For a longer but slightly out of date high-level description, see
>        [this.](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html)

I recommend following that last link and reading it.

Furthermore, this **PDF** [file](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall06/cos217/lectures/14Memory-2x2.pdf) which explain the inner workings of **malloc()** and **free()**.

Comment: Not `brk` & `sbrk` (both are nearly obsolete and thread unfriendly) but [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)

Comment: @Enzo Ferber : I dont think above answer explains malloc implementation for a newbie in a good manner.

Comment: and question is how they are done - if someone wants to know ..your answer doesnt address any of those but goes on to talk about sbrk which I believe might be different topic itself

Comment: @oneday I told you what **brk** and **sbrk** do so you'd understand the concept behind malloc. Then I gave you the source for the implementation of **malloc** and a high-level explanation for it. And as Basile said in the above comment, there's also **mmap** which I didn't talk about. Plus I don't get why **sbrk** is off-topic when discussing the implementation of a memory allocator. And I did try to keep it short and simple for a novice programmer, since it's resumed and contains several links instead of verbose explanations - so you would get the overall idea first _then_ dig into it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - Kernel virtual memory managers also have to be single-threaded when creating memory mappings.  After all, you can't have two threads in the same process wind up with overlapping virtual mappings to different chunks of physical RAM. So `mmap()` just shoves the threading bottleneck lower.