# Where I can to find C malloc/free source code of implementation for Windows in mingw?

Tags: c, malloc

I need to look in source code to understand what internally going on in `malloc` code when windows application is writing.

Comment: Then look in the source code ... this is not a lmgtfy-service .. :o

Answer (score 1):

As you have indicated that you are looking for mingw-specific implementation, it is easier to realize why you could not find the solution on your own.

Mingw is a "Minimalist GNU for Windows", thus you are probably looking for the [GNU libc implementation](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=malloc).

Further reading: [How is malloc() implemented internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479330/how-is-malloc-implemented-internally)

Answer (score 1):

Binaries built using the MinGW toolchain make use of the legacy Windows C Runtime, msvcrt.dll.  Its implementation of `malloc` basically just calls [`HeapAlloc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366597.aspx) to allocate memory.

To the best of my knowledge, source code for the Win32 heap (`HeapAlloc` and friends) is not publicly available.

Comment: Ah that's a good hint! Still a question, why do you call it *legacy*? Isn't this still the standard runtime for native win32 applications written in C?

Comment: @FelixPalmen:  The last version of Visual C++ that targeted msvcrt.dll was Visual C++ 6.  Subsequent releases included their own runtime libraries.  Visual C++ 2015 and Windows 10 introduce [a new system C runtime.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx)

Comment: Oh, thanks for the info! So probably mingw should link against THIS in the future ...