# mingw DLL from C#: why do I have to override new/delete?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, dll, mingw

I'm trying to call a minimal C function from C# on Windows 10. I use mingw/g++ to compile the C code into a .dll

It turns out that I have to define `opterator new[]` or compile the .dll using Visual Studio. Otherwise my C# program crashes with the following error:

`The program '[14740] Test.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.`

I'd really love to understand what exactly is happening here and how I can resolve this issue without overriding all the new/delete operators but still using mingw.

Here's the minimal example reproducing the error including a workaround (if `AddNewOperator` is defined `operator new[]` will be defined and the resulting .dll will work fine):

Test.cs (compiled/run with Visual Studio 2017):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
class Program
{
    [DllImport("libTest", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern int TestFunction();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("!!" + TestFunction());
    }
}
```

Test.cpp compiled with mingw (see below):

```
#include <new>
#include <cstdlib>

#ifdef AddNewOperator // This will fix the issue
void* operator new[](std::size_t sz){
    return std::malloc(sz);
}
#end

extern "C" {
int __stdcall __declspec(dllexport) TestFunction() {
        int* test = new int[3]; // removing this line will make everything work when building
        return test[2];
}
```

And here's the build script:

```
# Remove the following # and the compiled dll will work just fine
g++ -g -s -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 Test.cpp  #-DAddNewOperator
g++ -g -shared -o libTest.dll *.o -Wl,--subsystem,windows
```

**Edit:** compiling everything for x86 instead of 64 bit also fixes the issue (which is again no option for me)

Comment: I meant if I want to use `new[]`. So if I want to use `new[]` I either have to override `operator new[]` or I have to compile the .dll using Visual Studio.I changed that sentence for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

### You **must not** mix allocation / deallocation between compilers!

The problem you are facing is quite tricky and actually your program should crash every time, with or without the `void* operator new[](size_t){...}` definition.

If you debug your program, it actually should crash while deleting your `test` variable. This variable is created using mingw's new operator, but deleted using MSVC delete operator, and they are not [interoperable](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands). So you have to use mingw's `delete` function.

for a simple test you can just do:

**c++ code:**

```
int* test = nullptr;
int __stdcall __declspec(dllexport) TestFunction() {
    test = new int[3]; // note test is global
    return test[2];
}
void __stdcall _declspec(dllexport) CleanUp() {
    delete[] test;
}
```

**c# code:**

```
public static extern int TestFunction();
public static extern int CleanUp();
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("!!" + TestFunction());
    CleanUp();
}
```

---

### Why is your program not crashing if you redefine the new operator?!

I actually don't know for sure, but i think, the malloc implementation of mingw uses [legacy C runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32538835/1810087) which uses HeapAlloc for allocating and HeapFree for deleting your `test` variable. In short, you are simply lucky/unlucky it is not crashing when you custom defined your `operator new` and used `malloc` inside...

However, if you compile it using Visual Studio, both (dll and exe) are using the same runtime, so allocation/deallocation is done within the same memory space organizer. **BUT** still it is UB and you will run into problems! E.g.: If you create your libary with msvc10 and want to use this library with msvc14 same can happen here! I can remember some issues with code coming from a bug where the memory also was managed wrong; We used a library created with msvc11 but our code was compiled with msvc12...

Comment: It's clear to me that mixing new/delete from different compilers is dangerous, but why should my example code crash when I only use the new[] operator and no delete at all?
Also when I don't define any new/delete operator at all, I would expect that the implementations from the same compiler would be used, hence no crash...

Comment: @kunzej UB is UB. If your code tries to do things that aren't covered in the standard, then you can't say anything about what will happen.