# Where does malloc return memory?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management

I am learning about `malloc` function in C. I know how to request memory with

```
p = malloc(number_of_bytes);
```

and to free it later when it's not used with

```
free(p);
```

But I want to know something a bit more theoretical than this: I know that with virtual memory, there are three possibilities:

1. A virtual address can have no physical storage assigned (in pagefile or in physical memory)
2. A virtual address can have physical storage on the pagefile
3. A virtual address can have physical storage on physical memory

So, my question is:

Where does `malloc` returned memory is (I mean, is it on the pagefile, on the physical memory (heap maybe?))?

Comment: The C++ tag is not appropriate

Comment: Here is some good reading on the internal implementation of `malloc`: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3479330/335858).

Answer (score 6):

> is it on the pagefile, on the physical memory?

On operating systems with virtual memory management `malloc` has no idea of how the virtual memory that it allocates is mapped to physical memory, and that is entirely by design. `malloc` operates on a higher level than the virtual memory manager. To `malloc` all memory in the address space provided by the OS is the same.

Some pages may start with physical mapping, only to be swapped out into a file later on, and then back into memory as needed. However, operating system does all of this transparently to your program, so `malloc` is unaware of the physical memory.

Answer (score 4):

It is implementation specific. On Linux with [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/), `malloc` is often calling [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) to get more virtual memory from the kernel. `free` is generally marking a memory zone to be reusable by future calls to `malloc` but occasionally (for big memory zones) is releasing the memory with `munmap`

Use `strace` and study the relevant source code ... (Usually, `malloc` is implemented inside some free software standard C library on Linux). I believe that [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) has a nicely readable implementation of `malloc`

Read more about [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), [virtual address spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/).

See also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and think about the output of `cat /proc/$$/maps` and `cat /proc/self/maps`

On Linux specifically, read also about [Linux memory overcommit](http://www.etalabs.net/overcommit.html). It is a feature that I dislike and that I am disabling ...

Be aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). You can disable it (e.g. to have reproducible watchpoints under GDB).

For debugging `malloc` related issues (notably [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)) use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (and, with recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compilers, their `-fsanitize=` [debugging options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html)).

Comment: Also, Linux uses deferred page allocation, so freshly `malloc`ed memory space might not be backed by physical memory or swap space until the program actually writes to the allocated memory. Until then, it may just be occupying address space in the page table, with pages marked as "copy on write".

Answer (score 0):

Usually it will be allocated in the virtual memory if there's one. So let's assume it has one and the memory hardware is composed by a Hard Disk and RAM. If there's no space available in the physical memory (RAM), it will be allocated in the pagefile inside the Hard Disk.

Heap is the memory for objects and is allocated samewise. Just to clear up concepts here about the heap, imagine an embedded application without an operating system and without a virtual memory, if it's an object it will be allocated in the heap area in the physical memory (RAM), if it's not it will be allocated outside the heap area but still in the physical memory (RAM).