# what happens in the kernel during malloc?

Tags: c, linux, process, heap-memory, system

I was asked this question during an interview. What they wanted to know was when the user calls malloc(4) to allocate 4 bytes of memory how does the operating system (Linux) respond? Which subsystem responds to this system call?

I told him that malloc() will be serviced by the memory management subsystem. The malloc() implementation will go through the list of free memory(physical memory), we will call it free list, and find an appropriate chunk that is greater than or equal to 4 Bytes. Once it finds such a chunk, it will be deleted from free list and added to a used list. Then that physical memory will be mapped to the process heap vma struct. He didn't seem to be quite satisfied with this answer.How does the buddy system fit into this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: he's quite mad then. malloc() is implemented in usermode.

Comment: @Chris: Mostly. malloc might end up calling sbrk.

Comment: @Chris: Not necessarily.  The answer given here implies that `malloc()` allocates from physical memory which is wrongish.

Comment: Also, 'operating system' is not the same as 'kernel'; i think, when talking about unix, it's fair to construe 'operating system' as meaning 'kernel, bootloader, libc, and fundamental usermode programes such as init, getty, login, and friends'. Depending on exactly how the interviewer phrased his question, talking about what the allocator does in usermode might be a fair answer.

Comment: Guess he is not satisfied with your mixing between user call malloc and kernel function malloc. What you described should be functionality of kernel malloc.

Comment: OS agnostic version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work

Answer (score 88, accepted):

When user space applications call `malloc()`, that call isn't implemented in the kernel. Instead, it's a library call (implemented glibc or similar).

The short version is that the `malloc` implementation in glibc either obtains memory from the `brk()`/`sbrk()` system call or anonymous memory via `mmap()`. This gives glibc a big contiguous (regarding virtual memory addresses) chunk of memory, which the `malloc` implementation further slices and dices in smaller chunks and hands out to your application.

[Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-memory/)'s a small `malloc` implementation that'll give you the idea, along with many, many links.

Note that nothing cares about physical memory yet -- that's handled by the kernel virtual memory system when the process data segment is altered via `brk()`/`sbrk()` or `mmap()`, and when the memory is referenced (by a read or write to the memory).

To summarize:

1. `malloc()` will search its managed pieces of memory to see if there's a piece of unused memory that satisfy the allocation requirements.
2. Failing that, `malloc()` will try to extend the process data segment(via `sbrk()`/`brk()` or in some cases `mmap()`). `sbrk()` ends up in the kernel.
3. The `brk()`/`sbrk()` calls in the kernel adjust some of the offsets in the `struct mm_struct` of the process, so the process data segment will be larger. At first, there will be no physical memory mapped to the additional virtual addresses which extending the data segment gave.
4. When that unmapped memory is first touched (likely a read/write by the `malloc` implementation) a fault handler will kick in and trap down to the kernel, where the kernel will assign physical memory to the unmapped memory.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how Point 4 happens? All I want to know is how physical memory is finally allocated, and which part of the kernel code does that?
Thank you.

Comment: @ArjunBora No, that's a rather large topic. Please ask a separate question rather.

Answer (score 17):

`malloc` **does not** deal with physical memory directly. It deals with [paged virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory#Paged_virtual_memory) - although I'm not certain if it's true for every architecture out there.

When your program tries to allocate memory and the free list doesn't contain a chunk of equal or larger size than the requested size, an entire new page is allocated. The page size is architecture dependent (4096 bytes on x86). Page allocation is something only the kernel can perform, thus a `malloc` call may cause a system call. The new address is then added to the free list, and `malloc` manipulates the free list according to its implemention (check glibc for example).