# Malloc invoking system call

Tags: c

I was asked question in an quiz that a malloc() library call will always invoke mmap() or brk(). The answer is False. I am not able to get how it is possible?

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5716525/14311234

Comment: Suppose you call `malloc(1024)`. `malloc` calls `mmap` or `brk` to get the memory it needs for this. Later, you call `free` with that memory, and the memory allocation routines update their database to show the memory is available again. Then you call `malloc(1024)` again. This time, the memory allocation routines already have the memory, so they do not need to call `mmap` or `sbrk`; they just give you the memory that is already available.

Comment: As a trivial counterexample, imagine a `malloc` implementation that calls e.g. `mmap` for a giant piece of memory the first time it's called, hands out parts of that, and later on just uses the rest of that piece.

Comment: Is your question not answered in the answer you linked?

Comment: Is your question, why `malloc` is not always implemented using `mmap` or `brk`?

Comment: @sepp2k No, linked answer explained the internal working of malloc(), so from it I concluded mmap() or brk() are always invoked but Eric Postpischil cleared the confusion

Comment: @jackrock I think you may have misread at least parts of the linked answer then. The answer lists finding free memory as step 1 and makes step 2 (`sbrk`/`mmap`) conditional on step 1 not succeeding ("Failing that...").

Comment: Also, the linked answer talks about *a possible* malloc implementation, not *every possible* one.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you call `malloc(1)` it will ask the kernel for a whole bunch of memory, because the kernel has a minimum amount of memory it can give you. Then it will give you one byte of memory. The next time you call `malloc(1)` it will give you another byte out of that big block it allocated. And so on until that block is used up. Then it will allocate more memory from the kernel.