# What actually happens when objects are dealloc'd in Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, memory, memory-management, dealloc, heap-memory

I'd like to understand Objective-c's memory management at a lower level.  Say I have 100 bytes allocated on the heap to some Objective-c object.  **What happens to this 100 byte block when the object is `dealloc`'d?**

I'm curious about how the runtime knows that a block of memory is available for re-use after it's `dealloc`'d.  What happens to the actual bytes?  Are they set to random values?  Or perhaps they keep their values and just get overwritten by other objects later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They keep their value but are marked as unused and overridable.

This behavior is just like the malloc & free functions in C.

Comment: Does the 0th byte in the block mark the 100 byte block as unused?  Or perhaps the runtime maintains a table of unused address locations and the size of each location?

Comment: Usually, some bits before the memory zone being allocated (like a header for this zone) are used by the low level memory libraries to maintain information about the memory zone itself. Some other runtimes keep a "free-list" (list of free zones) and optimize their reuse to avoid memory fragmentation. But all this really depends on the libraries & runtime used (libc/stdlib) and allocator used

Comment: You will probably also find [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work) interesting (even if it is C/C++-related)