# Freeing memory issue causing my c program to crash but it doesn't crash while debugging?

Tags: c, debugging, memory, crash, valgrind

I've had trouble before with this same program because it makes lots of memory allocations. I got rid of most problems but I'm still having trouble with one particular problem. When I ran my program in Eclipse it compiles well but it crashes with this message

```
*** glibc detected *** /home/user/workspace/TTPrueba/Debug/TTPrueba: free(): invalid pointer: 0xb6bc0588 ***
```

When I ran it with Valgrind it tells me this

```
==31580== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==31580==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==31580==    at 0x804BEA3: termino (Menu.c:899)
==31580==    by 0x804BE05: computar_transformadas (Menu.c:840)
```

So the problem is that it is trying to free an invalid memory address but then I go step by step in debug mode and the program never crashes!!!! :(

Any idea why such a thing could happen? How come it works while debugging but not while running? This is pretty strange behavior.

```
for(phi=0;phi<360;phi++){

      for(j=0;j<par.param1[phi][0];j++){


              for(o=0;o<(par.prueba[phi][j][1]-par.prueba[phi][j][0]);o++){//AQUI 849

                 free(par.pixels[phi][j][o]);//HERE IS LINE 899 WHERE IT ALWAYS CRASHES

                 if(o==(par.prueba[phi][j][1]-par.prueba[phi][j][0]-1))
                     free(par.pixels[phi][j]);

              }


          free(par.prueba[phi][j]);

      }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Ah. The lovely--and not *nearly* rare enough--[Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) in it's natural habitat. See the beautiful camouflage pattern of the plumage? What's that? You can't see it? Well, yes. That's how you know it's there.

Comment: In the debugger the memory maybe zero, in your program this may not be the case. Try to change your mallocs to callocs.

Comment: "I go step by step in debug mode and the program never crashes!!!! " - welcome to the world of debugging!

Comment: You don't show your malloc code...

Comment: Lol @ the hisenbug but ok it gave me tips. Valgrind also warns me of unitialized values but I ignored them because I thought that if the debugger was fine then that wasn't a problem but apparently it is! Will it work if I initialize everything to 0 first?

Comment: Valgrind looks to be telling you exactly where the problem is -- Menu.c line 899 -- where one of the pointers involved is 0

Comment: Why the if(o==...) free() in the third for loop?

Comment: @user120115 because I can only free par.pixels[phi][j] after freeing all par.pixels[phi][j][o]

Comment: Ok, I replaced all my mallocs with callocs to make sure the values are initialized and valgrind no longer complains of uninitialized values but it crashes the same in the same place :(

Comment: @ChrisDodd if the pointer is 0 that means it will crash? So using calloc is useless in this case?

Comment: @Atirag: Why not put it after the for loop? Makes the code much harder to read - and adds redundant check. (Unless there is something I'm not seeing here.)

Comment: @user120115 Yeah the loop is also implicitly checking that the par.pixels[phi][j] was initialized. If I put it after the loop there's no check so it gives an error

Comment: @Atirag: Ah. OK. Sorry for waisting your time ;)

Comment: @user120115 No don't worry! thnx for trying to help! :)

Answer (score 0):

One likely reason -- the debugger could be changing the memory layout of things, so when memory is corrupted, it happens to be in an "out of the way" place.

Or the debugger might be causing allocated memory to be zeroed which may not be happening in a production run.

Comment: or the implicit synchronisation of using the debugger to stop  at breakpoints is changing the timing interaction of threads... (if multithreaded)

Comment: Not multithreaded so that's not the problem. I think some unitialized values are the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not surprising. For example if  par.pixels[phi][j][o] is not initialized. It can contain anything, in a debugger environment, you have different memory layout par.pixels[phi][j][o] may become 0, so free didn't crash.

Comment: Besides using calloc (ensuring the pointers are initially set to NULL, making any attempt to erroneously dereference them obvious), it's a good practice to set pointers to NULL after freeing the memory they point to (for the same reason). Or sometimes when debugging, a "poison" value (say, 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef) that will stand out in error messages / debug prints.

Comment: How can I do that? for example if I do free(par.pixels[phi][j][o]); should I do something afterwards?

Comment: you can't fix it if you never initialized it. Check where it came from, it had to be assigned a result from malloc() for it to be a valid free() candidate.

Comment: Question: If par.pixels[phi][j][o] is a signed int and the value that it holds is bigger than 32767 that will cause a problem while freeing the memory right?

Comment: par.pixels[phi][j][o] should not be a signed int, it should be a pointer type, it is suppose to contain the return value of a previous malloc() call. The value is not important.

Comment: But this is how I do the malloc par.pixels[phi][j][o] = (int *)calloc( 2, sizeof ( int ) ); and according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work it might cause a problem if the value it holds is bigger than the defined type since it could overwrite other memory locations.

Comment: if the type of  par.pixels[phi][j][o] is a pointer, it will be the same as the return type of malloc, and since you cast (int *), that has to be the case, the post you mentioned is not related to your problem and I think you misunderstood it. The most likely cause of your problem, I am guessing here, is that you never actually written into that location and then you go and free it.

Comment: Ok somehow the thing fixed it, I think it was a combination of things that were wrong. Thanks a lot for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

One problem that I see is that you free `par.pixels[phi][j][o]` where `o` looping from zero, and then *access* `par.pixels[phi][j][0]`, which just have been free'd!

You also free `par.pixels[phi][j]` but continue looping accessing `par.pixels[phi][j]` and freeing pointers that a no longer valid.

Comment: I never access par.pixels[phi][j][0] after freeing par.pixels[phi][j][o] I access par.prueba[phi][j][0].

Comment: Also when I free par.pixels[phi][j] I make sure it is the last loop so the next it will come out of it and stop freeing memory