# Real memory allocation done by cudaMallocPitch

Tags: c++, cuda

While debugging a memory leak in my cuda code, I was running some tests and wondered what was allocated on the GPU besides what I asked for.

Here is the test I am running:

```
__HOST__ __forceinline__
double memoryUsage()
{
    size_t free_byte = 0;
    size_t total_byte = 1;
    cudaMemGetInfo(&free_byte, &total_byte);
    return free_byte;
}

...
double mem = memoryUsage();
cudaMallocPitch((float**)&device_ptr, &pitch, width * sizeof(T), height);
ASSERT(mem - memoryUsage() == pitch * height);
...
```

Of course the assertion here fails. I simplified the code a bit, but note that I check for any error from `cudaMallocPitch`.

Does someone have an explanation for this? Could the memory managment system on the GPU (malloc) use this memory? Or did I simply mis-understand something?

If it can help, here are some values I get for some allocations of `400 x 400 x sizeof(uint16_t)` arrays:

```
pitch= 1024; mem-memoryUsage()= 0; pitch*height= 409600
pitch= 1024; mem-memoryUsage()= 1.04858e+006; pitch*height= 501760
pitch= 1536; mem-memoryUsage()= 1.04858e+006; pitch*height= 838656
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question.

The answer to this question ([Why doesn't CudaFree seem to free memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10394755/why-doesnt-cudafree-seem-to-free-memory)) is apparently what is happening. `1.04858e+006` is the page size that is used to allocate memory on the GPU in my case.

Comment: You are also comparing the wrong things. The size of the buffer allocated in your case is not `pitch * height`. It should be `width * height * sizeof(T)  + pitch`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! If Im not mis-taken. `pitch` is the width in bytes of the allocation (ie. `width + offset`). According to the Cuda documentation, accessing an element is done via `T* pElement = (T*)((char*)BaseAddress + Row * pitch) + Column;`. Therefore, I think that `pitch * height` is the correct formula.

Comment: `pitch*height` should give the size of the allocation in bytes, ignoring overhead.

Comment: @Rippalka Sorry about that. I mistook pitch for offset. My bad.

Comment: Nothing wrong about that, alignements in Cuda can sometimes be confusing. I appreciate your intention though! Thank you