# How does free() 'know' that passed pointer is valid?

Tags: c, pointers, free

I know that an invalid pointer leads to undefined behaviour but how does free know whether a pointer is valid or not?

Is there kind of a checksum at the beginning of each block in free list?
something like:

```
if((*ptr) == 'CHECKSUM'))
  free
else
  do something undefined
```

Comment: Usually, it doesn't know, and just crashes (or corrupts something).

Comment: Find answer for your question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work

Comment: It doesn't have to know. The whole point is that it's allowed to assume the argument is either null (in which case it does nothing) or a pointer to a object obtained by (or as if by) `malloc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I know that an invalid pointer leads to undefined behaviour but how does free know whether a pointer is valid or not?

The only check is whether the pointer is null or not.  If it's a null pointer, free (by specification) will do nothing.

Otherwise, `free` just tries to "free" the memory, making the assumption that it was memory allocated by `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`, which can make anything happen (typically bad things) - hence "undefined behavior."

Comment: That's why it's a good idea always to set your pointer to NULL immediately after you've freed it.

Answer (score 4):

There might be. But in general, it doesn't. For many implementations, `free` just assumes its input is valid and plows right ahead as though that's true. It is perfectly within its rights to do that.

This is why the behaviour is "undefined": it's impossible to predict what'll happen if the pointer isn't valid. Random areas of memory might get trashed, during the operation of `free` and/or later when some other heap operation is performed; potentially leading to unpredictable behaviour in unrelated code. The program may crash immediately in `free`, or later in some apparently unrelated locations.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't know. It just supposes it is valid and acts appropriately.

If this assumption was wrong, destruction of important structures might have occured - and what happens then, is not known. Thus the undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Since the pointer is invalid, `free` tries to read the "book-keeping information" as if the pointer was returned by `malloc` and valid, which usually leads to freeing some random address pointed by that invalid pointer, leading to corruption/crash etc.