# Does calling malloc multiple times waste memory?

Tags: c, memory-management

Currently working on a code I realized that it used to call `malloc` multiple times (around 10 million calls) and allocated small chunks (around 10 bytes) every time.

I changed the code a little and instead of calling `malloc` 10 million times I now call `malloc` 10 times allocating a large chunk of memory (10 million bytes) every time.

With this change I noticed that peak memory consumption of my code changed from ~15 GB to ~14 GB.

Why is this happening? Does `malloc` allocates some extra chunk with every call?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

definitely. Because `malloc()` allocates some amount of bytes for meta-data. so if multiple malloc() leads to more meta-data.

This [link](http://www.inf.udec.cl/~leo/Malloc_tutorial.pdf) gives you more detail about how malloc allocates memory as well as metadata.

Comment: Yes... but allocating a big block and parcelling it yourself most likely doesn't really change that, because then *you* need to apply that metadata... Rule #1 of optimizing applies: Measure, optimize, measure.

Comment: @DevSolar: well, clearly not as much: the OP measured it already.

Comment: @ams: Granted. But it's dangerous to take an extreme example (like the OP's 10 million calls) and abstract them into hard and fast rules ("always do your own memory management, it's faster and saves memory"). >10 years of maintenance coding have taught me how bad such hard & fast thinking can go in the long run. ;-)