# realloc() an incremented pointer

Tags: c, malloc

- Platform: Linux 3.2.0 x86 (Debian Wheezy)
- Compiler: GCC 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

I am wondering what will happen if I attempt to realloc() a pointer that has been incremented. For example

```
char *ptr = NULL;
size_t siz = 256;

ptr = malloc(siz);

ptr = realloc(ptr + 5, siz * 2);
```

What will the return value of the `realloc()` call be? I also know that `realloc()`'s documentation states that the pointer passed to it must have been returned by malloc(), `calloc()`, or `realloc()`. I am assuming that means I cannot `realloc()` an incremented pointer but I have been unable to verify that assumption.

Comment: when you write "dereference" you actually mean "added to".  Dereferencing means you apply the `*` or `[]` operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That wouldn't work any predictable way, the results would be undefined. The 1st argument you pass to `realloc` or `free` must be returned by `malloc`, `realloc` or `calloc`, or it must be `NULL`.

In this case it is not true for `ptr[5]`, because `ptr[5]` is uninitialized. You will also get a compile error or warning, because `ptr[5]` is not a pointer. But even if it was a pointer (e.g. `char **ptr;`), it would still be uninitialized, so the condition is false, and thus the results are undefined, and most probably the process would crash.

In this case it is not true for `ptr + 5` either, because `ptr + 5` is was not returned by `malloc`, `realloc` or `calloc` (but `ptr` was), and it's not `NULL`. The behavior is undefined in this case, most probably the process would crash.

Comment: Not so much that `&ptr[5]` is uninitialized but it wasn't the value returned by `malloc()`.

Comment: I do not mean dereference I actually mean the verb equivalent of pointer arithmetic what ever that is.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: `ptr[5]` is indeed uninitialized in this case, so it can't be initialized to a value returned by `malloc`, `realloc` or `calloc`.

Comment: Yes, `ptr[5]` is indeed uninitialized, but that is immaterial to (the revised version of) the problem.  The problem is that `ptr+5` was not returned by `malloc()`.

Comment: My answer covers both the old and the new version of the problem (so far).

Comment: May also be passed `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` family function allocates memory and then *returns pointer to that block*. `ptr + 5` is not returned by `malloc`, so you can not pass it to `realloc` as it expects its first argument to be a pointer return by `calloc` or `malloc`or `realloc` itself. It will invoke undefined behavior.

#### C11: 7.22.3.3:

> [...]Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, **the behavior is undefined**.

Answer (score 2):

As pts says, the behavior is undefined. [Here's a reference to the relevant documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/realloc.html). I expect that you'll get a segfault, but you can't know how this will behave on your particular system without testing.

Trying out out on [ideone.com gives you a memory error](http://ideone.com/8hk6YD):

```
int main(void) {
    char *ptr = NULL;
    size_t siz = 256;

    ptr = malloc(siz);

    ptr = realloc(ptr + 5, siz * 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Yields:

```
*** Error in `./prog': realloc(): invalid pointer: 0x09dc900d ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(+0x75e72)[0xb7641e72]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(realloc+0x275)[0xb7645ad5]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(realloc+0x28b)[0xb7645aeb]
./prog[0x80483e8]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0xb75e58f5]
./prog[0x804840d]
```

Implementations of `malloc` differ from system to system, but the basic idea is that, somewhere, your OS [has a list of pointers and associated regions of memory that have been `malloc`'d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work). When you call `realloc`, it looks for the address you've passed to it in its lookup table. It can't find it, so it gives up and dumps core.