# How does malloc() know where the heap starts?

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

When the OS loads a process into memory it initializes the stack pointer to the virtual address it has decided where the stack should go in the process's virtual address space and program code uses this register to know where stack variables are. My question is how does malloc() know at what virtual address the heap starts at? Does the heap always exist at the end of the data segment, if so how does malloc() know where that is? Or is it even one contiguous area of memory or just randomly interspersed with other global variables in the data section?

Comment: It can be hard-coded.

Comment: I imagine that would be platform specific. Are you interested in getting an answer for a specific platform?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do malloc() and free() work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work)

Comment: @RSahu Let's say Linux.

Comment: @ControlAltDel I understand the concept of how malloc works, I just don't get how it knows where the heap actually starts.

Comment: Are you satisfied knowing that the OS would know this information, and `malloc()` simply asks?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`malloc` implementations are dependent on the operating system; so is the process that they use to get the beginning of the heap. On UNIX, this can be accomplished by calling [`sbrk(0)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/brk.html) at initialization time. On other operating systems the process is different.

Note that you can implement `malloc` without knowing the location of the heap. You can initialize the free list to `NULL`, and call `sbrk` or a similar function with the allocation size each time a free element of the appropriate size is not found.

Comment: Ahah, the light turns on. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: The other mentioned answer was confusing because of this line "The sbrk system call moves the "border" of the data segment.", and from my understanding the data segment it where global data is stored. So I assumed that the heap must be at the end of the data segment, but didn't get how malloc() could know where the end was.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>This only about Linux implementations of `malloc`</sup>

Many `malloc` implementations on Linux or Posix use the [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) syscall to get some quite big range of memory. then they can use [munmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/munmap.2.html) to release it.

<sup>(It looks like [sbrk(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sbrk.2.html) might not be used a lot any more; in particular, it is not ASLR friendly and might not be multi-thread friendly)</sup>

Both these syscalls may be quite expansive, so some implementations ask memory (using `mmap`) in quite large chunks (e.g. in chunk of one or a few megabytes). Then they manage free space as e.g. linked lists of blocks, etc. They will handle differently small mallocs and large mallocs.

The `mmap` syscall usually does not start giving memory range at some fixed pieces (notably because of [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Try on your system to run a simple program printing the result of a single `malloc` (of e.g. 128 `int`-s). You probably will observe different addresses from one run to the next (because of ASLR). And [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)-ing it is very instructive. Try also `cat /proc/self/maps` (or print the lines of `/proc/self/maps` inside your program). See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

So there is no need to "start" the heap at some address, and on many systems that does not make even any sense. The kernel is giving segments of virtual addresses at random pages.

BTW, both [GNU libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and [musl libc](http://musl-libc.org/) are [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). You should look inside the source code of their `malloc` implementation. I find that [source code of musl libc](http://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree) is very readable.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, you use the [Heap functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366711(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the process heap memory. The C runtime will allocate memory blocks on the heap using `HeapAlloc` and then use that to fulfil `malloc` requests.