# Freeing an invalid pointer?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
void resolve_paths(char* inputdir)
{
    char** tokens = malloc(64*sizeof(char*));
    char* ptr;
    char* slash = "/";
    int i = 0;

    ptr = strtok(inputdir,slash);
    while(ptr != NULL){
        if(strcmp(ptr,"~") == 0){
            ptr = getenv("HOME");
        }
        tokens[i] = (char*)calloc(64,sizeof(char));
        tokens[i] = ptr;
        printf("token[%i] = %s\n",i,tokens[i]);

        i++;
        ptr = strtok(NULL,slash);
    }
    int j;
    printf("freeing each element of tokens\n");
    for(j = 0; j < i; j++){
        printf("freeing token[%i]\n",j);
        free(tokens[j]);
    }
    free(tokens);
    puts("leaving resolve_paths\n");
    return;
}
```

My Output:

```
before call
token[0] = a
token[1] = b
token[2] = c
freeing each element of tokens
freeing token[0]
freeing token[1]
Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007ff96dca12b2 ***
```

I guess I simply don't understand how malloc/calloc and free work. Why does this code run into a seg fault?

Comment: Note - you should always check return of `malloc` .

Comment: Will say `if(ptr == NULL){ /*show an error and exit*/ } ` be a sufficient check?

Comment: Do you allocate memory to ptr ? No , check those to whom you allocate memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tokens[i] = (char*)calloc(64,sizeof(char));
tokens[i] = ptr;
```

This code doesn't do what you think it does. First you allocate 64 bytes and store the address in `tokens[i]`, then you replace that address with `ptr` (thus losing the just allocated one which leaks away).

Probably you meant something like

```
tokens[i] = calloc(64,sizeof(char));
strncpy(tokens[i], ptr, 64);
```

which allocates the memory and then copy the string pointed by `ptr` into it. Mind that you don't need to cast the result of calloc or malloc in C since a `void*` is implicitly convertible to any other pointer.

In the end you try to `free(tokens[i])` but the address contained is just a local address of `inputdir` adjusted by `strtok`, so it's not a dynamically allocated address which you can correctly free, that's why you get the error.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Also, would changing the 2nd bit of code to `tokens[i] = calloc(strlen(ptr),sizeof(char)); strncpy(tokens[i], ptr, strlen(ptr));` be beneficial? If so, should I do it this way, or is it unneccesary?

Comment: No, it's an error. You must limit `strncpy` to the size of the buffer, not on the size of the source string. By using `strlen(ptr)` you basically don't use any limit and you can find the problem you are trying to avoid, if `strlen(ptr) > 64` you overflow over the length of `tokens[i]`

Comment: @Jack: You should carefully read  the strncpy manpage before recommending its use. At least read the **warning**. http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy

Comment: @Connal: I recommend the simple `tokens[i] = strdup(ptr);`. If you don't have strdup, `tokens[i] = malloc(strlen(ptr) + 1); strcpy(tokens[i], ptr);`

Answer (score 2):

Your are going wrong at `tokens[i] = ptr;`. You are assigning a pointer with that, not (as you probably expected) copying a string into the allocated memory, so you are freeing something you haven't actually allocated later on.

You have to use strcpy/strncpy for copying ptr into tokens[i]. Use something like `strncpy(tokens[i],ptr,63)` instead of `tokens[i] = ptr;`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as answering how `malloc()`,`calloc()` work, go here: [How do malloc() and free() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work) ,
excellent answers for your question.