# Freeing memory in C or C++

Tags: c++, c

Let we declare a pointer

```
int *ptr;
ptr=malloc (10 *sizeof (int));
free (ptr);
```

The question is how `free()` will free memory. Let `int` be of 4 bytes and the memory will be 40 bytes for `int`.
The compiler will understand to remove first memory location provided by `malloc` but how it will clear another 9 int data that is other 36 bytes?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work

Comment: `malloc` is C, `new` is C++ - so why tag this C++?

Comment: Because in C++ by typecast ptr=(int*)malloc (10 *sizeof (int)); it will work                  Therefor tagged it in C++ also.

Comment: memory allocation, acquired by a call to `malloc()` (and family of functions) is an entry in a data structure kept in the heap.   When a pointer to allocated memory is passed to `free()`, the actual address is prefixed in the heap with certain 'header data' that your program should never directly access.  the `free()` function uses that header information to link that whole allocated memory data block back into the 'available' memory in the heap.  So, only the one call to `free()` is necessary, as malloc and free have no concept of an array of int, as indicated in the posted code,

Comment: Using `malloc` in C++, even for such simple things as an array of integers, is a bad habit. Try to get used to using `new` and `new[]` if you program in C++.

Answer (score 3):

`malloc` leaves notes that `free` reads. In particular, it leaves a note that says how many bytes were allocated.

Comment: I don't know that thanks it will be useful.