# Free a memory block in the heap

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm currently working on a school project, and i try to understand the operations behind the `free()` function.

`malloc` will allocate a block in the heap. 
If we want to free this block, will this block be totally set at `'0'` values (with brk usage)

**or**

will it only be set as 'available' to allow erasement on it (data replacement...)

Answer (score 4):

`free` only deallocates the memory, it doesn't fill it with `0`-s.
After freeing it, writing to, or reading from that memory will cause undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Viktor Simkó  answer  `free` will remove the header and add it back to the free memory list. If it forms a larger block with the surrounding free blocks these will be added together to give a larger block when user demands larger block. If a whole page is now free the allocator will, most likely, return the page to the OS.

For more information have look on [How do malloc() and free() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work?rq=1)