# mprotect on heap aligned memory works mysteriously

Tags: c, linux, malloc, mmap

So I am trying to check if I can properly change the access rights on mmapped allocated memory using `mprotect` and this is what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main()
{
        int pagesize;
        pagesize = getpagesize();
        void *p;
        p = malloc(pagesize);
        getchar();
        int q = posix_memalign(&p, pagesize, pagesize);
        getchar();
        int a = mprotect(p, pagesize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);
        getchar();
        free(p);
}
```

Now after each function i am using `getchar` to analyze my memory segment using `cat /proc/<pid>/maps` file and this is what I get:
(only showing the information regarding heap as that is my only concern)
After the `posix_memalign`:

```
01776000-01798000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

After the `mprotect` function:

```
01776000-01778000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
01778000-01779000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
01779000-01798000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
```

So if you notice the heap allocated before gets divided into three parts after i use `mprotect` and only the second part of the heap gets the access permissions that i gave in the function.
Why does this division happens and why does only the second region of the divided heap gets the permissions?
Note: I have searched manpages and have found absolutely nothing regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You allocated `0x1000` bytes at address `p`, which is `0x1778000` in your example. When you called `mprotect` with these parameters, it did indeed work as you wanted and marked `01778000-01779000 rwxp`.

Your question could thus be more aptly phrased as, why does `posix_memalign(3)` seem to allocate more space than you requested?

Lets take a look at `man posix_memalign`:

> POSIX requires that memory obtained from posix_memalign() can be freed using  free(3).

But how does `free(3)` know how much bytes to free? It needs to store it somewhere outside the page you allocated. And how do subsequent invocations of `malloc(3)` or friends know where to find freed blocks? These need to be stored somewhere too.

And it is no surprise that the heap allocator stores the data structures it uses to manage the heap on the heap.

If you want a more low-level way to allocate a page, use `mmap(2)`:

```
p = mmap(0, getpagesize(), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

This memory is managed by you, when you call `munmap(2)`, the mapping is deleted by notifying the kernel directly. No recycling or management done in user space.

- More information on what `malloc(3)` does:
  [How do malloc() and free() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work)
- Wikipedia's article on C's dynamic memory facilities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation
- glibc's implementation of `malloc(3)` et al: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c#L3016
- Blog post on glibc's implementation: 
  https://sploitfun.wordpress.com/2015/02/10/understanding-glibc-malloc/

Comment: Slightly unrelated: You are leaking memory by overwriting `p` and the proper return type for `main` is `int` not `void`.

Comment: How did you come to know i allocate 1000 bytes (since I tried to allocate `pagesize` bytes which is 4096 bytes) and the address for that is `0x1778000` as after allocation the memory shown is `0x1776000-0x1798000`?Please elaborate that part, the rest I understood.

Comment: @AbhinavJain Memory related stuff is usually represented in hexadecimal. 4096 in decimal equals 0x1000 in hex. If you `printf("%p", p)` you will get `0x1778000`, add `0x1000` to that and you will arrive at `0x01779000`, just like procfs told you.

Comment: Ok but what the previous `0x1000` were used for?

Comment: Data internal to the `malloc(3)` implementation. Check out the last two links to see what kind of data glibc stores there.