# The use of the free function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I want to know please where i have to use the "free" function?

does I use it when i already use the "malloc" function or I use it with any declared pointer?

Note: in the two cases the `liste` type is defined as below:

```
typedef struct Node * liste;
```

`Node` is a also a structure:

```
struct Node { 
    int value; 
    Node *N;
};
```

First case

```
liste l; 
free (l);
```

second case

```
liste l;
l=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
free (l);
```

thank you in advance !

Comment: What does your book say on the topic? This should be covered fairly early on.

Comment: In the first case no memory was allocated so none can be `free`d. In the second case you are [casting the return value from `malloc'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) but it is a different type. Are you hiding a pointer behind a type definition?

Comment: @WeatherVane for the second case, the liste type is defined as bellow: typedef struct Node * liste; and Node is a also a structure. struct Node { int value; Node*N;}

Comment: @Constellation [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54857762/edit) to add this information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do malloc() and free() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [man page for `free`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free) states the following:

> The free() function frees the memory space pointed to by ptr, which
>   must have been returned by a previous call to malloc(), calloc() or
>   realloc(). Otherwise, or if free(ptr) has already been called before,
>   undefined behavior occurs. If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.

In your first case, the use of `free` is invalid because `l` is not initialized.  The second case is valid (assuming `liste` is a typedef for a pointer) because `l` is assigned an address returned by `malloc`.

Comment: in the first case, the liste type is defined as bellow: Node * liste; and Node is a also a structure. struct Node { int value; Node*N;}

Comment: @Constellation Then this answer stands.  Also, add that information to your question.

Comment: done but i dont understand yet the use of free. if p is a pointer --> we can apply the "free" function or we have, imperatively, to use the "malloc" function, to use then, the "free" function?. thank you in advance .

Comment: @Constellation `free` is used to de-allocate memory that was allocated by `malloc`, as stated in the quoted passage.

Comment: so can not be used in the first cas?

Comment: @Constellation No, because `l` was never set to anything.

Comment: and if a set it to an already created linked list. liste a; l=a->N; can i use "free(l);" if yes, which memory will be de-allocated?thank you a lot.

Comment: @Constellation It depends on what was assigned to `a->N`.  If it was memory allocated by `malloc` then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: i understand and if we have two pointers which point on a linked list, the size of the list=3 elements. " liste a, b;" memory is allocated using "malloc". if we use "free(b)", the memory allocated for the linked list will be de-allocated? --> the " a" pointer will point on Null?

Comment: @Constellation freeing a pointer does not set the pointer value to NULL.  You still have to do that yourself.

Comment: Dear @dbush, i mean when i have two pointers pointers the same linked list or a dynamic table. if I free a pointer, the pointed structure will be lost or i can always have it using the other pointer?

Comment: @Constellation once you free the memory it is invalid.  Any it is undefined behavior to use a pointer that points to memory that has been freed.