# Mechanism of malloc and free

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm studying about the mechanism of malloc() and free() function in C. After few test, I
discern that the mechanism of those function follows worst fit algorithm, doesn't it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    void* base;
    void* a = malloc(100);
    base = a;
    void* b = malloc(60);
    printf("%ld   %ld\n", a-base, b-base);
    free(a);
    a = malloc(40);
    printf("Free then reallocate a\n%ld   %ld\n", a-base, b-base);
    void* c= malloc(1);
    printf("Allocate c c\n%ld   %ld   %ld\n", a-base, b-base, c-base);
    free(b);
    b = malloc(1);
    printf("Free then reallocate b\n%ld   %ld   %ld\n", a-base, b-base, c-base);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0   112
Free then reallocate a
720   112
Allocate c c
720   112   768
Free then reallocate b
720   800   768
```

Comment: None of those 3 algorithms are "optimal algorithms". They're just "algorithms". They're optimal for some usage patterns, and brutally terrible for others.

Comment: Related?: [c++ - How do malloc() and free() work? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work)

Comment: Malloc's allocation strategies vary between implementations. To get a good answer, you should pick one OS in particular, and ask about it. For the most part, malloc has different memory pools dedicated to objects of various sizes. It attempts to hit a trade off between minimizing memory waste, maximizing speed, and minimizing CPU/Memory overhead of overly-granular book keeping.

Comment: As always, if you have specific memory usage requirements in your program that are super important, you should code for them.  You cannot rely on any particular allocation strategy in the standard library, and implementations will vary.  BTW, you really shouldn't be doing pointer arithmetic on unrelated objects.

Comment: You can look up the implementation of malloc and free with whatever library you're using. For example, there's some documentation for the glibc versions here: https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals .

Comment: I have just edit my post, sorry everyone

Comment: (ps: pointer arithmetic on void* is not legal c, although it's a gcc extension). The correct printf format for intptr_t is not `%ld` but `PRIdPTR` (or some other options from stdint.h)

Comment: "best fit, first fit or worst fit". Those are strategies that you can apply *as is* in an idealized world. In the real world the answer is: "is complicated".

Comment: It's possible there was some dynamic allocation when you called `printf()`, so the memory you think should be reused is no longer available.