# Bytecopy of Float array into Byte buffer creates hard fault (C - STM32F4xx/F103)

Tags: c, stm32

**Abstract:**
I need to copy all elements of a struct containing a float array into a byte buffer, in order to send it out via UART. The next call of malloc after the copy operation leads (allways) to a hard fault, which is a good indicator that somewhere the memory gets corrupted, but I have no clue where this could happen (after 2 days debugging ...)

**Description:**
I have a nested Typtedef, that contains a float array:

```
#define DRV_SCALE_MAXSZ 32  
#define DRV_CHANNELS 2

typedef struct {
    float x1;
    float step;
    uint8_t aSz;
    float Y[DRV_SCALE_MAXSZ];
} DRV_linscale_TDS;

typedef struct {
    DRV_linscale_TDS scale; 
    uint32_t active;
} DRV_ChScale_TDS;

DRV_ChScale_TDS DRV_scale[DRV_CHANNELS] = {0,};     // Channel Scales
```

And I need to copy the whole content of either DRV_scale[0] or [1] into a byte buffer, in order to send it out via UART.

As a little extra complication I copy it element by element, with a copy function, that reverts the bytes of the value if necessary:

```
#define TXBUFSZ 255  

volatile uint8_t TxBuf[TXBUFSZ] = {0,};

void FillTxBuf(uint8_t idx, uint8_t *pBo) {
    if(idx < DRV_CHANNELS) {
        volatile uint8_t *pDst = TxBuf;
        *pDst++ = DRV_SCALE_MAXSZ;
        *pDst++ = DRV_scale[idx].active;
        pDst += COM_ElementCopyU32((uint8_t*)&DRV_scale[idx].scale.x1, pDst, pBo);
        pDst += COM_ElementCopyU32((uint8_t*)&DRV_scale[idx].scale.step, pDst, pBo);
        *pDst++ = DRV_scale[idx].scale.aSz;

        uint8_t i = *pDst;
        float *pSrc = DRV_scale[idx].scale.Y;

        while(i--) {
            pDst += COM_ElementCopyU32((uint8_t*)pSrc, pDst, pBo);
            pSrc++;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the code above is a shrinked version just for explanation. In reality *TxBuf[TXBUFSZ]* is a static preallocated byte buffer (declared extern in the header file, and defined in the c file)

The function COM_ElementCopyU32 looks like this:

```
uint8_t COM_ElementCopyU32(volatile uint8_t* pSrc, volatile uint8_t* pDst, uint8_t* ByteOrder) {
    // @brief   copy data from Source to Destination and revert bytes if necessary
    // @param   U8* pSrc: Pointer to data Source Buffer
    // @param   U8* pDst: Pointer to Destination Buffer
    // @param   U8 ByteOder: 0 = little endian, 1=big endian
    // @return  u16 number of copied bytes

    if(pSrc && pDst) {
        if(*ByteOrder != isBigEndian) {
            pDst[0] = pSrc[3];
            pDst[1] = pSrc[2];
            pDst[2] = pSrc[1];
            pDst[3] = pSrc[0];
        } else {
            pDst[0] = pSrc[0];
            pDst[1] = pSrc[1];
            pDst[2] = pSrc[2];
            pDst[3] = pSrc[3];
        }
    }

    return(sizeof(uint32_t));
}
```

**The issue:**
as soon as the line

```
pDst += COM_ElementCopyU32((uint8_t*)pSrc, pDst, pBo);
```

is involved, the call of *FillTxBuf()* leads to an hard fault with the next call of *malloc()*. The next *malloc()* comes immediately after *FillTxBuf()* when the CRC32 is appended to the byte stream. The general workflow is: check the incoming request, fill the Tx Buffer, append the CRC32 and send it out.

**What have i tried to solve this so far?**
Well, i tried a lot:

1. I removed the line mentioned above. As long i do not copy any bytes
   from *DRV_scale[idx].scale.Y* to *TxBuf[]* in the while loop is
   disabled, anything works fine.
2. I replaced float *pSrc = DRV_scale[idx].scale.Y;* with * float *pSrc =
   DebugArray;* where DebugArray is a "stand alone" static pre-allocated
   float array of the same size as *DRV_scale[idx].scale.Y* (32
   Elements) and anything works fine
3. I tried to copy the Elements from *DRV_scale[idx].scale.Y* to
   another float array (lets call it "DupArray"), which worked fine but
   when I tried to copy "DupArray" bytewise into *TxBuf[]* it crashes.
4. and I tried to copy the Elements from *DRV_scale[idx].scale.Y* to
   *TxBuf[]* in another function, right after Hardware initialisation, using the same code (copy & paste), it worked fine
5. I tried several versions of the *DRV_linscale_TDS* Typdef, with the
   Byte variable at the end and at the beginning, with no effect
6. I checked if there would be a buffer overflow in the while loop, but
   as expected there is none, as the total number of copied bytes is
   ~100, so there are 155 bytes "free" (note: the overrun prevention
   code is still in the original code but left out here for better
   readability)

I have no clue what's going on here. Each part of the code - when I debug it separatey - works fine. Copying the original Array to another float preallocated float array works fine, copying the float array to a byte array and writing it back works fine. Just if I do exactly that, whats working fine verywhere else, in that particular function, it generates a hard fault.

Through all the testing and debugging it points out clearly: the hard fault only happens, when I try to copy *DRV_scale[idx].scale.Y* into *TxBuf[]*, anything else works without problems.

One might say: well, then somewhere before *FillTxBuf()* *TxBuf[]* gets corrupted, but why works anything flawless in *FillTxBuf()* when I use a different float array than *DRV_scale[idx].scale.Y*?

**Remarks:**
One possible workaround would most probably be to split up the struct and use separate preallocated "stand alone" float arrays. The reason why I glued it together in one variable is, that this variable is written to flash and I'd really like the approach FlashWrite(VariablePointer, SizeInBytes) ...
If there is no other option, i will have to separate it, but I'd really like to understand in which pitfall I stumbled in ...

**The Question:**
Where could I search?

Comment: `uint8_t i = *pDst;` is fishy. When this statement is executed, `pDst` points at the next byte to be written. So the referred location hasn't been initialized with a valid value it.

Comment: yes, i allready figured that out, too. In the "original" version its: >>uint8_t i = DRV_scale[idx].scale.aSz; *pDst++ = i;<< but that does not change anything about the fact, that copying the data from DRV_scale[idx].scale.Y to another array or byte buffer corrupts the memory. I have now traced down to this fact: if I "touch" the Y-Array in the Struct, the memory gets corrupted. I guess i will work with pointers and external arrays, because I can't find an explanation or solution to this issue.  I never had such issues with predefined arrays in structs so far ...

Comment: or explained the other way round: if I do this: >> float DRV_Ybuf[DRV_SCALE_MAXSZ] = {0}; uint8_t i = DRV_SCALE_MAXSZ; float *pSrc = DRV_scale[idx].scale.Y; float *pDst = DRV_Ybuf; while(i--) *pDst++ = *pSrc; << the memory gets corrupted (reliably and reproducable)

Comment: It also looks as if `TXBUFSZ` is too small as `DRV_scale[DRV_CHANNELS]` is likely 288 bytes long.

Comment: nope, it should be big enough. I just write either DRV_scale[0] or [1] to the TxBuffer, not the whole DRV_scale array at one time.

Comment: Update: it's completely strange! What I found out is: if I fill the float arrays in DRV_scale[idx].scale.Y in a loop (while/for does not matter) it creates a hard fault. If I write the elements of the Y-Array one by one - that means **one line of code for each Array element** - it works. What is going on there?

Comment: If you can't debug it on chip, it should be compilable on PC too, so just use valgrind for checking memory issues

Comment: at least i have the confirmation, that I have to handle one of the worst problems in C/C++ - see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1119334/14720421 But on the other hand, i made some progress. I wrote a new debug version of the code and I am now allmost 100% sure, that using *COM_ElementCopyU32()* in a loop causes the problem. It has nothing to do with the float array in the struct, it's the process of copying the floats into the byte buffer in a loop. I'm absolutely sure, because in my debug code I don't use an float array, but just a float variabe, that is updated each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the problem but you can use **union** to send struct data within a array. Here is an example;

```
typedef union
{
  your struct object; (should be packed 
  struct)
  uint8_t uartBuff[your struct size];
}unExample;
```

Variables in union use same memory address via this you can easily send your data.

Answer (score 0):

hardfault errors always because of pointer-alingment

i usually use my own library for binary serialize in c
this [library](https://github.com/Ali-Mirghasemi/Stream) can help you

it's have examples in c and for STM32F4 already

it's support endiness and have configuration part for customization